# Proof of "Taylor Series"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

We know that , according to the *Taylor Series* :

> $$f(x)=f(a)+\frac {f'(a)}{1!} (x-a)+ \frac{f''(a)}{2!} (x-a)^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3+ \cdots \tag{1}$$

And then Maclaurin series as $a=0$.

But how to prove it?

I have googled it and searched for it in my books but I really have not come across any where where it gives the proof of $(1)$.

Please help ... Just links to the full proof is also appreciated..

Thanks!!

Comment: Assume that we can define a polynomial such that $$f(x)=a_0+a_1(x-a)+a_2(x-a)^2+...$$
If we put x=a, then we get $f(a)=a_0$. Now derive and put x=a in the derivative to get $f'(a)=a_1$ and so on.

Comment: The proof depends on f(x) being an [analytic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function)  and (at an intuitive level at least) is then about finding the coefficients of the polynomial by repeated differentiation

Comment: @Galc127 Thanks!! But where did those $1!, 2!, 3! , \cdots$ come from?

Comment: @NeilRoy, we will find for example $a_3$. Deriving three times we get $$f'(x)=a_1+2a_2(x-a)+3a_3(x-a)^2+... \\ f''(x)=2a_2+3!a_3(x-a)+... \\ f'''(x)=3!a_3$$ hence $a_3=\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}$ and so on. As mentioned in comments and answers, this method assumes that the error approaches 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, we don't.
Taylor's theorem states that 
$$f(x)=f(a)+\frac {f'(a)}{1!} (x-a)+ \frac{f''(a)}{2!} (x-a)^2+\ldots+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n+ R_n(x)$$
where quite a few things can be said about $R_n(x)$, for example
$$ \lim_{x\to a}\frac{R_n(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0$$
or
$$ \forall x\exists \xi\colon (a<\xi<x\lor x<\xi<a)\land R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$$

But we do not have in general that $\lim_{n\to\infty}R_n(x)=0$, hence not necessarily 
$$f(x)=f(a)+\frac {f'(a)}{1!} (x-a)+ \frac{f''(a)}{2!} (x-a)^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3+ \cdots $$

Answer (score 1):

The way you state this is to imprecise to give a proof. The correct statement is that $$f(x) =\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k +r_N(x,\ldots)$$
Without the last term, the so called remainder (for which various different expressions are known, see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem), the statement is not correct. The proof of the statement with remainder (usually by induction) is rather easy using the fundamental theorem of calculus or the mean value theorem.

**Edit** (the representation of $f$ by an infinite sequence of this kind is only true for so called real analytical functions)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at chapters 7 and 11 (Specially section 11.9) of the well-known book:

Calculus, Vol. 1: One-Variable Calculus, with an Introduction to Linear Algebra

by Tom. M. Apostol.

There is a rigorous study of Taylor polynomials and series in those chapters.